# Cookies in javascript not working with live.click function

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I want to get the value of one text box if a particular button is clicked. I can't send the value through url so I tried using javascript.
Here is my php code:

```
<a href="yahoo/Connected.php">
<input type='button' class='button' id='yahoo' value='Yahoo'></a>
<p>Your name, emails will be sent with your name in Subject</p>
<input type='text' class='inviteename' id='text' name='name'>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script>
$('#yahoo').live('click',function() {
var inviteename = $('.inviteename').val();
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/; domain=.example.com";
}
createCookie('invitee_name',+inviteename,'1');
});
</script>
```

Through this, cookie is not being create, can anyone spot what wrong I'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. your html is invalid. Why wrap input fields in a link?
2. `.live` is deprecated, you should use `.on` - I use on submit here.
3. you should use a [cookie jQuery plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) instead of wrapping a named function into your click.

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Z2PP4/)

Please note the demo is using "p" instead of "name" to actualy do something.
Hit F12, Run the demo once then reload to see the cookie was set

```
<form id='yahoo'  action="yahoo/Connected.php">
<input type='submit' class='button' value='Yahoo'></a>
<p>Your name, emails will be sent with your name in Subject</p>
<input type='text' class='inviteename' id='text' name='name'>
</form>
```

using

```
$(function() {
  $('#yahoo').on('submit',function(e) {
    var inviteename = $('.inviteename').val();
    $.cookie('invitee_name',inviteename);
  });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but this doesn't resolve my problem, cookie not being created.

Comment: You need to install https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie - more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery). Also you had a + in the invitee name - not needed unless you want to convert a string containing a number to a number before it is stored as a string

Comment: There is no link for demo, can you post it again? And with removing '(' it doesn't work as well.

Comment: It seems that just doesn't work on my server, I will look something to it. Example's working fine.

Comment: Are you looking at the cookie in the same folder or on a different page in a different folder?

Comment: I'm looking at the developer tools only whether cookie has been set.

Comment: So `console.log($.cookie("invitee_name"))` shows undefined? Are you running from a server? Is the browser set to accept cookies from that server? You cannot set a cookie from a file loaded from harddisk

Comment: That doesn't display anything & yes cookies are well accepted, in fact this is the live server I'm playing with. I've many more cookies already running, this one is first in javascript.

Comment: It should display EITHER undefined OR the value - not nothing - can you post your code in a fiddle that shows it doing nothing? You can fork mine to get the frameworks and plugins

Comment: It's done, thanks a lot buddy, problem was in other file as I was including foundation js file once this cookie.js file is loaded. Loaded it at the last & it worked like a charm. It was seriously hell of an issue, but a sweet fruit at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this little script, to check or creating cookies actually works ...

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['MyCookie'])) {
    setcookie ('MyCookie', 'yes', time() + 3600);
    echo "cookie is CREATED";
    }
    else{
    echo "cookie EXIST";
    }
?>
```